# Is it possible to lock status bar and navigation bar on Android M

Tags: java, android

In my project I need to lock the status bar and navigation bar to avoid end user entry the original launcher, and in API 21 I've tried to used method of startLocktask(), both bar function can be disable, but I cannot calling third party APK, So, if there have any chance to lock both bar, but still can starting third party APK?

Comment: I guess you are talking about the kiosk mode api, which only applies to your app. So a short answer: no, your app cannot determine the behaviour of the status and navigation bar of a third party app.

Answer (score 0):

I found this of use time ago, maybe works for you too:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    // Hide the Status Bar
    getWindow ().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView (R.layout.main_layout);

}

@Override
protected void onResume () {
    //Log.d (TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume ();

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    // Hide the Status Bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}

}
```

Beware when the screen rotates, you should keep it in mind too.

Hope it helps.